# Can you help me to source a screw thread G1 3/4 inch to anything to fit in my stainless steel heat exchanger?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid

Last year I bought s heat exchanger for my above ground 12 foot paddling pool. I also bought a pair of 'gee' one and three quarter thread pva plastic
adaptors to push in 50mm plain blank tapered holes. I can't find the invoice or who i bought them from I want to upgrade my Heath Robinson, Rube Goldberg tape and glue circuit with something a bit more click and connect maybe with fewer hose clips. I searched 'G1 3/4' i searched G7/4 inch thread I searched G one and three quarter thread to no avail. Where the hell have they gone?  Are they extinct?  Is there an exclusive club with a special handshake I have to join?  Please help.

Comment: a plumbing supplier : brass plumbing fittings

Comment: I'm in the uk and have tried plumbing shops.

Comment: Then as per my answer next stop is a machine shop.

Comment: You need to search using 1 3/4 BSP.  You will also need the thread pitch, number of threads in one inch.  In the UK, it shouldn't be hard to find, though 1 3/4 inches is pretty big for household use.

Comment: I accidentally found that the compression fittings on a standard waste pipe connector here in the uk are 7/4" G type which is 1 and 3/4. Hurray I'll be trying it out when it's light. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe G denotes British standard pipe thread, so they will be more difficult to find. See here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Standard_Pipe

If you can't find local and you live in the US, try a supplier website like McMasterCarr or Granger, etc.

Could this be what you are looking for?
https://www.mcmaster.com/british-standard-thread-pipe-fittings

Comment: I'm in Britain, still no joy. The link you sent doesn't have one and three quarters anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you cannot find them then your other option is to find a machine shop.

Any decent machine shop can make you two from brass stock with the other end machined to match the copper pipe or other fitting you need to adapt to.

What supplier did you use for the heat exchanger as they usually carry fittings as well. Perhaps worth contacting them.

Comment: I bought the heat exchanger from eBay and as they don't sell them any more they don't have the details of it. I found fittings for it when i bought it a year ago but they don't seem to turn up on searches now.

Comment: @ColinEllis so if they were on ebay were they a reputable company's online presence or a one-off person selling something like "off the back of the lorry"? If the former than look for the makers name on the heat exchanger and proceed from there.

Comment: It seemed to be a reputable company selling through ebay, they made various sizes. Also they didn't sell fittings, I had to buy them elsewhere.

Comment: It turned out to be vidaxl.com who don't sell heat exchangers any more.